# (void?) in DrRacket

Tags: racket, void

How to use the built-in function void?. The code

```
(void? void)
```

returns #f. Deeply confused.

Appreciate your help. And apparently I have to type more stuff in order to get it posted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`void` is a *function* that returns the special constant `#<void>`. So the function itself is not void, but its result is:

```
(void? (void))
```

produces `#t`. See http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/void_undefined.html and/or http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/void.html.